# как правильно строить сервер на nest js

Tags: javascript, json, архитектура, клиент-сервер, nestjs

у меня есть уже готовый фронт, и мне надо как-то передавать массив из примерно таких элементов:

```
export interface IContent {
  type: IContentTypes;
  content: string | string[][] | 'line' | File;
}
```

вопрос в том как правильно создать контроллеры, чтобы сохранять и файлы и другие данные. Я пробовал создать такую архитектуру и основная проблема была в файлах, потому что для них как будто нужен свой отдельный route и service. Я был бы рад если бы вы дали например правильную архитектуру сервера для сохранения всего, либо подсказали как все данные вместе передавать туда с фронта.

заранее благодарю

Comment: Можете в качестве прмера рассмотреть мой сервис, в нем реализована загрузка файлов на сервер, проверка их уникальности, так же есть и CRUDы, реализована чистая архитектура/ddd. Однако, он написан на golang, но проблем для рассмотрения примеров, проблем быть не должно.

https://github.com/Borislavv/streaming